# Trying to Javascript on Website

Tags: javascript

Clarifying the question:

If I run the Js on the button class, it clicks all the buttons. If I run it on the div class, it returns undefined. I want to click all the buttons `user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn` that are below a specific div class `user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting` .

Hey there Stack Overflow! Trying do do a click all via Chrome Console

Why doesn't

`javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting '); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }`

work?

HTML is

```
<div class="UserActions   UserActions--small u-textLeft">
    <div class="user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting " data-user-id="81502422" data-screen-name="DPiperScout" data-name="Derek Piper" data-protected="false">
      <span class="UserActions-moreActions u-inlineBlock">
          <button type="button" class="js-tooltip unmute-button btn small plain-btn" title="Unmute @DPiperScout" data-placement="top">
            <span class="Icon Icon--muted Icon--medium"><span class="visuallyhidden">Unmute @DPiperScout</span></span>
          </button><button type="button" class="first-load js-tooltip mute-button btn small plain-btn" title="Mute @DPiperScout" data-placement="top">
            <span class="Icon Icon--unmuted Icon--medium"><span class="visuallyhidden">Mute @DPiperScout</span></span>
          </button>
<div class="dropdown ">
  <button type="button" class="user-dropdown dropdown-toggle js-dropdown-toggle js-link js-tooltip btn plain-btn small-user-dropdown" title="More user actions">
    <span class="user-dropdown-icon Icon Icon--cog Icon--small"><span class="visuallyhidden">User Actions</span></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-caret">
      <span class="caret-outer"></span>
      <span class="caret-inner"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please show us how you placed the JavaScript on the page, *"Why doesn't this work"* isn't a good explanation of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am throwing the JS into Chrome Console.

`var items = document.querySelectorAll(".user-actions.btn-group.not-following.not-muting");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].click();
}`

Did not work, either. Getting an "undefined" result.

Comment: Tried using jquery

`$(".user-actions.btn-group.not-following.not-muting").click();`

still a no-go. This does not come back undefined, it just returns a list in console, does not "click" the buttons.

Comment: @JaromandaX: It does actually accept a space-separated list of class names.

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher `.click()` isn't going to do anything if there isn't any `.click()` event handlers on that item.

Comment: Ignore the `undefined` result. You always get that after a statement that doesn't return anything (like your loop). What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: Hmm. I can use the original inputs[i].click(); on button classes, but not div classes.

Comment: If I run the Js on the button class, it clicks all the buttons. If I run it on the div class, it returns undefined. I want to click all the buttons `user-actions-follow-button js-follow-btn follow-button btn small small-follow-btn` that are below a specific div class `user-actions btn-group not-following not-muting `.

Comment: Added clarity above.

Comment: A `div` element has no default behavior when clicked. What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: I want to click the button class buttons that are below the specific div class. I have to focus the javascript command on the button class, but that click all of them regardless of the div class they are contained in.

Comment: Need to do an if-then statement. If div class=* then click button class =*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to click all the buttons. Your selector should be:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".user-actions.btn-group.not-following.not-muting button");
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you can simply select all the buttons within the `div` you want using `element.find("button")`:

```
$(".user-actions.btn-group.not-following.not-muting").find("button").each(function(){
    this.click();
})
```

Comment: there is no jquery in the question

Comment: @JaromandaX In the comments the OP mentioned they tried using a jQuery selector.

Comment: there is no jquery in the **question** and there's no reason to assume the website he is trying it on has it loaded